# HAML: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How convert this code to HAML?

```
<h4 class="media-heading"><%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user.profile_url, target: '_blank' %> says
          <small class="text-muted">[at <%= comment.created_at.strftime('%-d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S') %>]</small></h4>
```

I tryed so, but dispaleyd errors:

```
%h4.media-heading 
      = link_to message.user.name, message.user.profile_url, target: '_blank' says
        %small.text-muted [at '#{= message.created_at.strftime('%-d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S')}']
```

Comment: You should check for the indentation. You can verify the haml at http://htmltohaml.com/

Comment: @maximusツ Indentation has nothing to do with that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is HAML supposed to know what that dangling "says" is, if you leave it on the same line?

`=` in HAML denotes a line of **Ruby**. You can't throw random words on the same line and expect Ruby to understand what is Ruby and what is a plain old string.

```
%h4.media-heading 
  = link_to message.user.name, message.user.profile_url, target: '_blank'
  says
  %small.text-muted [at '#{= message.created_at.strftime('%-d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S')}']
```